# Is there a way to retrieve a C# app's current memory usage?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr, memory-management

I am automating some profiling tasks and want to log heap space and generation sizes real-time.  The [profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384547.aspx) seems awfully complicated for what I need, and it seems to listen in on individual allocations and collections, which isn't that important to me.  Profiling tools are a great help of course, but I was looking for a more flexible, programmable interface.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The term 'current memory usage' is a little loosely defined. Do you mean the working set? Whatever it means, you can use different properties such as `VirtualMemorySize`, `WorkingSet`, `PrivateMemorySize`, etc. from the process class to retrieve it.

```
long workingSet = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64;
```

Answer (score 6):

There are performance counters for a lot of this stuff and if you can't use Perfmon, you can access counters through the Diagnostics API.

Answer (score 3):

Once I had to find a memory leak in a legacy code, I came accross this solution:
Start "tasklist" with appropriate parameters as a process and read the output either from stream or from file.

e.g.

```
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq notepad++.exe" /FO CSV /NH
```

Output is:

```
"notepad++.exe","7132","Console","1","21.004 K"
```

Not that elegant, but works in any programming language on Windows without additional dependences (C++/Qt in my case).