# Log Memory Used by C# Console Application

Tags: c#, logging, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to retrieve a C# app's current memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461139/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-a-c-apps-current-memory-usage)

Is there a way to measure and log periodically the memory usage by a C# console application?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most reliable way is using an external tool: A memory profiler. I usually recommend [ANTS memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/).

Comment: +1 - ANTS Memory Profiler has worked very well for us in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a timer, and have it periodically check the memory usage using the Process component; log using a robust logger such as log4net.