# C# Application, Monitor Memory Consumption

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, memory-management

Is there a way I can monitor memory consumption from within my C# application?  I would like to dynamically change a variable based upon the amount of memory my program is using.

I have some code completing queries to a data base and temporarily holding this data before I write it to a file. I also have code that allows the user to manually change at what point the data is dumped from memory and written to the file, but I want the program to handle this automatically.

For example; if my process reaches 700,000K memory usage (like as viewed from `Task Manager`, then decrement an integer and continue processing.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461139/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-a-c-sharp-apps-current-memory-usage

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes I did, quite a bit in fact. I only found methods of monitoring processor usage!  Thanks for your help though! :)

Comment: Hope it helped you, but try to google hard, it will find you what you want 99.9%. I googled and first page got the results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the current memory usage this way:

```
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var mbUsed = (proc.PrivateMemorySize64/1024)/1024;
```

PrivateMemorySize64 is a long representing the amount of memory used in bytes.

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what I was looking for!  A straight forward, and simple solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can search about PerformanceCounter class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use performance counters and monitor virtual bytes or bytes on all heaps or use the Process class and VirtualMemorySize64