# Finding memory usage of multiple App Pools using c#

Tags: c#, iis, application-pool, iis-10

I'm attempting to find how much of each App Pool's memory is being used through c#

This is what I have at the moment:

```
List<ApplicationPool> pools = new List<ApplicationPool>();
List<WorkerProcess> processes = new List<WorkerProcess>();

ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
ApplicationPoolCollection appPools = serverManager.ApplicationPools;

foreach (ApplicationPool pool in appPools)
{
    pools.Add(pool);
}
```

This gives me a list of all the App Pools I have running, but none of the properties of the ApplicationPool object give me any information about it's usage or and real-time data.

Have I got completely got the wrong end of the stick?

How do I find out the information I want?

I haven't been able to find a straight answer anywhere, but apologies if this has been answered before.

Cheers

Comment: I would think WMI would probably be the solution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525265(v=vs.90).aspx or performance counters https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0a6c9f07-a70c-4c3d-b93d-5dfef593c744.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use system.diagnostics to get the working set.

The example in the link could be modified to get the working set for all w3wp.exe processes.

[Is there a way to retrieve a C# app's current memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461139/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-a-c-sharp-apps-current-memory-usage).

Comment: Does exactly what I need, all I need to do now is figure out out to differentiate between each of the w3wp processes. Cheers

Comment: If the application pools are using ApplicationIdentity the username of the process should be the ApplicationPool name